# ffmpeg detect loud noises in audio

Tags: ffmpeg

Does ffmpeg have the inverse of the `silencedetect` filter? I'm recording audio, and I tap on the mic to mark the places to split the recording at.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect

Comment: Does tapping on the mic result in higher peaks than what would normally occur in the audio? If so, I'd gate the audio with a high ratio and use silence detection to find out when the gate kicks in again.

Comment: @slhck Ah, that's an interesting approach, and should definitely work — thanks! Any other approaches to solving this problem come to mind? Basically, I want to be able to easily mark points in a recording which to later split at. I know that I can just add a silence of a specific length, but that's a bit more time consuming than a quick tap (there are a lot of split marks!).

Comment: See post linked as a duplicate. You may have to apply some filtering or and find your own thresholds on the output.